# Best Way . Sending Complex MVC Models in a single Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post, models

i am developing mvc applications for more than 1 year. And i came across some very complex forms. The user should fill some fields , upload files and add many rows in 2 or 3 or more kendo grids.

i want to post back all these data in a single post back to controller and save everything...

Μy models are consisting of fields... two or three lists (kendo grids) and blobdata (attachemnt files)

like

```
public class GenericRequest: FormBase
{  
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public string StatuName { get; set; }
    public Guid? TypeGID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string ContractDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual List<WorkPackage> WorkPackages { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Order>Orders{get;set;}
    public virtual List<Attachment>Attachments{get;set;}
}
```

what is the best way and technique working with such complex models. adding all the data and posting a full object back to controller ? what pattern should i use ? Of course there is a chance to avoid adding kendo grids and working only with mvc objects. in that way, how can i add items to the lists in client and send everything back to controller ?

Comment: Just use strongly typed html helpers to generate the html for your properties. For the collections, use a `for` loop - e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.WorkPackages.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkPackages [i].SomeProperty ...}` or use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the types in your collections. It will all bind correctly on post back.

Comment: Should this question not be moved to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) . Answers will be opinionated

Answer (score 2):

Always try to bind complex models with Partial views.

Lets say in your case we can bind WorkPackages , Orders,Attachments in different partial views and Basic details will be in separate partial view.

All those partial view will be render inside Single view.

When post operation happen you can manage those for individual partial views so only required model data will post.

Comment: so in this case i have to use a viewmodel right ? in my case only attachment data is rendered in a different partial view because i think it is unnecessary to send it among with other objects

Comment: Yes Viewmodel is good to deal with Complex models. it will provide you flexibility to perform operation on separate entities of models.

Comment: Using partial views for complex child objects and collection is **not** the correct way (you would need to pass complex prefixes to the partial so the controls will be correctly named). Instead use custom `EditorTemplates`